# From RAC to Standby RAC With Active Dataguard

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, rac, dataguard

I have oracle  database 11.2.0.3 with RAC feature  , with 2 node on oracle linux 6.4 :

```
ol6-112-rac1 and ol6-112-rac2
```

I want to create active data guard with RAC feature from this database , these active dataguard with rac option has 2 node :

```
ol6-rac1-guard,ol6-rac2-guard
```

I want to use this document for creation active data guard from rac database to rac database :

http://www.oracledba.org/11gR2/dr/11gR2_dataguard_RAC_to_RAC.html#Create_Physical_Standby

I do the steps in this document , all of things is ok but in step " Start
the Managed Recovery Process "  after i want to switch log in primary ,
switch log is not occurred on standby database .
After " tail of alert log " on standby database and  executing " Switch log " on primary , this error is occurred :

```
tail -f  /ora01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/racguard/racguard1/trace/alert_racguard1.log
Wed Feb 17 04:37:57 2016
Media Recovery Waiting for thread 1 sequence 76
Error 12154 received logging on to the standby
FAL[client, USER]: Error 12154 connecting to rac for fetching gap sequence
```

This is my mistake , can any one help me ?

Comment: Your TNS entry in tnsnames.ora contains an incorrect service name that the listener does not know of. Fix that, and try again.

Comment: Can you explain more ? because in primary tnsnames.ora , i have entered the information for standby1 and standby2 (node of standby db ) , in tnsnames.ora of standby db , i have entered information about primary database . is it wrong ?

Comment: Post the contents of `tnsnames.ora` and `lsnrctl status` for your listeners and scan listeners. Somewhere in `tnsnames.ora` you specified a `SERVICE_NAME` that does not exist at the corresponding destination.

Comment: ok , i do them and the information of that on below link : http://workupload.com/archive/wp539s8N , is it ok ?

Comment: Can anyone help me ?

Comment: @saeed.sh are you able to connect to primary using Sqlplus with sys user? if you cant then what error message do you get? and there is no listener file for primary db in your link.

Comment: yes , i can connect to sqlplus from standby to primary with sys user and tnsname entries

Comment: @saeed.sh show the output of `SQL>show parameter FAL_SERVER`. Also include the alert log file of primary as well as standby.

Answer (score 0):

In your tnsnames.ora on the standby side the needed tns alias for 'rac' is missing. In a data guard configuration it is extremely important that all members can resolve all other members.